# Flash message to be always shown even when scrolling down

Tags: css

I am showing a flash message when user click on some buttons and the flash message is positioned on my page with the following:

```
<div id="flash-message">
    <div id="flash-success" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible flash-success" role="alert">
        <button href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</button>
                File uploaded
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am using the following CSS:

```
.flash-success {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.flash-error {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

The flash message is shown correctly but if I scroll, I cannot see it. Only if I scroll back to the top.

Comment: You'll want to look into `position: fixed`

Comment: Your postion is absolute so it will be positioned to it's relative parent. `position: fixed` will get you what you want.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the answer, I didn't get that fixed was for the screen and not the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options that I believe would work.

```css
#flash-message {
    position: fixed;
}

/* OR */

#flash-message {
    position: sticky;
    /* Define at what point you would like it to stay fixed */
    top: 0; 
}
```